# How to use value under cursor in the shell command?

Tags: cursor, variables, shell

Is it possible to use word under cursor in shell command? Say:

```
Elvis
^ cursor here

then
:r! echo <word_under_cursor>
```

and get "Elvis" read in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are typing interactively in the vim command line you can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> to include the current word or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to include the current WORD.

If you are writing a function or a command you can use `expand('<cword>')` or `expand('<cWORD>')` for the current WORD version.

Like in:

```
function! Hello()
  echo 'The current word is: ' . expand('<cword>')
  echo 'The current WORD is: ' . expand('<cWORD>')
endfunction
```

Comment: Yes, using `<C-r>_<C-w>` solves it. Using expand() is not possible in command line mode as far as I see.

Answer (score 1):

There is something to remember: Vim treats the commands differently. Some of them accept literals and cmdline-specials, so you can do

```
:r !echo <cword>
```

(or maybe `:.!echo <cword>`)

While others accept VimScript expressions, so it could look as, for example,

```
:put=expand('<cword>')
```

(or maybe `:put=system('echo ' .. expand('<cword>')`)

So the syntax of VimScript is heavily context-dependent.